# SOAP action error C#

Tags: c#, soap

I am trying to post XML data VIA SOAP PROTOCOL, i am new to web-service here is my code

```
public HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest()
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://46.211.211.144:8080/");
        try
        {
            webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:Action", "http://46.211.211.144:8080/test1");
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            //WebRequest.ContentType = @"application/xml; charset=utf-8";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
            return webRequest; 

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String strerr = ex.ToString();
            return webRequest;
           // Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

In the above code while in runtime i am getting - Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters. is it correct what i am using there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. `SOAP:Action` is not a valid header name. I think you're looking for `SOAPAction`.

You might want to read about WCF too, instead of manually crafting HTTP requests.